# How to use the Regular Express of the end pattern in the next pattern not the entire string?

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I am trying to find the categories in a website by using Regular Expression.
I typed `(?<=class="category-section" data-id=")(.*)(?=" id="nav)`
but it return the whole string to me, and what I see it start from the first pattern after `data-id="` until the end pattern has `" id="nav`

For Example:

```
<div class="category-section" data-id="Motors" id="nav-1">
<div class="category-section" data-id="Fashion" id="nav-2">
```

I expected to get Motors and Fashion in the matches but it wil return

```
 Motors" id="nav-1"> <div class="category-section" data-id="Fashion
```

I dont get it....

Comment: `data-id=(['"]?)(.*?)\1` - the second capture group contains what you want, although you really should be using an XML parser for this.

Comment: Obligatory: **Do Not Use Regex To Parse HTML! **

Comment: If you're doing something in Notepad++ or something, you should use this `(?<=data-id=")(.*)(?=")`

Comment: @TomLord Please explain to OP *why* parsing HTML with regexes is a road to sorrow. Just saying "don't do that" isn't much help.

Comment: Which language are you trying to implement this in?

Comment: @andylester This is explained EVERY time a question like this gets asked, i.e. Hundreds of times per day. There's even a link to the famous response right above my comment.

Comment: I know it does, but OP doesn't know that.  Also, the famous response is not helpful.

Comment: @JackyCheung Please note that parsing HTML with regexes is error-prone and difficult.  The HTML can be in a zillion different formats.  Here are some examples: http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html

Comment: @Jan I usually do C# programming but this time my VP wants me to provide a pure RE instead of a application in C# -_-" my VP is trying to train me to become a expert in RE

Comment: @JackyCheung I would explain to the VP that this is not good challenge; there are many better ways to test yourself with complex regex tasks. HTML *cannot* be fully parsed via regex. HTML is a context-free grammar, which by its very definition is *irregular*.

Comment: Given a *restricted* input like this, yes it's certainly doable with a regex. But this is not the "right" way to do it; and with arbitrarily complex HTML your pattern *will* fail in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`data-id=".*?"`

It will return two matches, then correspond to `data-id="Motors"` and `data-id="Fashion"`.

So, you can replace the `data-id=` and `"` sings to get your desire value, inside attributes.

**Edit 1:**

By using simple js functions, you can retrieve this value:

```
<div class="category-section" data-id="Motors" id="nav-1">Content1</div>
<div class="category-section" data-id="Fashion" id="nav-2">Content2</div>

<script>
    (function() {
        var data = document.getElementsByClassName('category-section');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data.item(i).getAttribute('data-id'));
        }
    })();
</script>
```

**Output:**

```
Motors
Fashion
```

Comment: it works @Abe but my VP wants me to use pure RE to get the target instead of using function to cut it off >_<" I am die-ing now.....even my team leader doesn't know much in RE. How come they focus a volunteer, me, to become a RE expert...........

Comment: What language or resource you're using? It's pure JS? we can build a simple function to make this.

Comment: I do C#, but this time just do pure RE